# Java: Str_replace a character with a new line "\n"

Tags: java, string, replace, line

Here's the code:

```
String text = "hello, my name, is john smith.";
```

How do I make it into:

```
String text = "hello\n my name\n is john smith.";
```

Thanks!

Comment: As far as library functions go, this one is fairly easy to find. What did you try?

Comment: check for `replaceAll()` method

Comment: Do you want to `replace` `','` with `'\n'`?

Comment: Thanks, but how come this doesn't work:

    String content = "askodja|two|three four five|six seven|monday";
    String qwe= "|";
content = content.replaceAll(qwe, "\n");
It just adds a new line everywhere.

Answer (score 13):

```
text = text.replace(',', '\n');
```

Comment: You get the +1 for using `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`, and reassigning to the `text` variable.

Comment: Why do I get an error using speechmarks "", but it works using ' apostrophes? And it works, thank you.

And why is replace better?

Comment: @Keppil I up voted for the same. :)

Comment: @user2421111: `replaceAll()` uses regular expressions, which is unnecessary here, `replace()` does not.

Comment: @user2421111 `replace()` is better because you just want to replace a character. `replaceAll()` would unnecessarily try to compile a regex out of your first parameter.

Comment: method replace want characters for input and with "," symbols you put string so if you want to write character you must use ','

Answer (score 1):

With the replaceAll method:

```
text.replaceAll(",","\n");
```

Comment: On all the solutions people give me, why does it say:
No suitable method found for replace(java.land.String,char)
method java.lang........ is not applicable;

Comment: You probably tried `replace(",",'\n')` which is wrong.

Comment: @user2421111 call replace with single quotes to denote you're passing a character like `replace(',', '\n')`

Comment: So, it seems to only work with " if I use String, ' for character?

Am I right? Please confirm and say my username.

Comment: @user2421111 Yes, '' delimits a char and "" a String, read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
text = text.replace(", ", "\n");
```

NB: The first parameter is a comma followed by a space.  It will replace the comma and the space following it with a new line.  It looks much nicer this way, unless you wanted the spaces in the beginning.

Comment: Why do I have to use a speechmark?

Comment: You have to use `""` because this you need to pass `", "` as a `String`, since it can't be represented by a single character.  There isn't a `replace` that takes a `char` and `String`, so you must also past the newline character as a String `"\n"`